# Integrity Error in Sqlite Database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to import large amounts of data into a sqlite DB through python 2.5.  The data consists of strings, but there are multiple duplicates in the data.  An example;

```
addres,type_code, location
123,01,work
123,01,mall
132,49,home
132,33,home
```

My issue is that when loading the data I get an `Integrity error, address and type_code are not unique`.  This is true, in fact there will be thousands of times when these 2 rows are not unique.

How am I able to enter this data into my database?

Comment: Post your sqlite schema. `sqlite .dump foo.db`

Answer (score 3):

your table probably has primary key set as addres + typ_code. If those three fields are indeed should be unique in that particular table then redefine primary key to include all three fields addres, type_code and location. That would fix the problem you facing.

Comment: I wish it were that simple...Initially I had my primary key set as all 3, but when that didnt work I recreated the table and had no primary key, still didnt work.